# How do I compare two lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if two Expression<Func<T, bool>> are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673205/how-to-check-if-two-expressionfunct-bool-are-the-same)

I need to compare two lambda expressions, to check equality. Basicly, the two following lambda are identical:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp1 = (Foo f) => f.Bar().StartsWith("F");
Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp2 = (Foo b) => b.Bar().StartsWith("F");
```

How can I check if `exp1` does the same thing that `exp2` does?

Comment: Does equality mean semantically the same, or that they both produce the same result?

Comment: for the reference, there is a solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24528357/2528649), I have checked it with this code, works well.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to use IComparer or mock classes

View [c-sharp-lambda-expressions-and-icomparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870197/c-sharp-lambda-expressions-and-icomparer) and [comparing-simple-lambda-expressions](http://www.codethinked.com/comparing-simple-lambda-expressions-with-moq)